# How to enable the POST permission on Twitter Developer App?

Tags: python, api, post, twitter, tweepy

In order to post a tweet on Twitter using Python's tweepy, it requires us to enable POST permission(read and write permission) for our app. How to enable that permission on the developer portal for our app?

Answer (score 4):

(note, this answer applies at the time of writing Jan 2022; user interfaces may change)

You have a choice of using OAuth 1.0A or OAuth 2.0. The latter is new and may not yet be supported by all code libraries.

In the developer portal:

- select app name in sidebar -> app Settings page
- **User authentication settings** -> Set up button
- toggle on **OAuth 1.0a**
- set **Read and write** App permissions permissions
- specific URLs in general auth settings section. If you are not going to build a full sign-in with Twitter flow, you can use e.g. http://localhost here.
- Save button

You will now need to select the Keys and tokens tab under the app settings, and Generate Access token and Secret, in order for them to have the new permissions.

You may also use OAuth 2.0 for this, and select the user scopes (permissions) within your code. Check the Twitter documentation for more details.

Comment: Hi, does that mean I can set "callback URL", "website URL" to whatever I want if I just want to create a bot without UI?

Comment: Those two fields will not be used if there is no UI or sign-in flow, so you can set them to something like `https://localhost`

Comment: This answer should be upvoted and the accepted answer

Comment: "Website URL (required)", doesn't accept "https://localhost" or "https://localhost" or "https://127.0.01", any idea what I can use? tx v m

Comment: `https://example.com` is another one you could use.